# Multiple Iterations - Self joining the file/table

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

The problem I am facing is quite tricky(may be for me!)

I have a csv file which has 2 columns which are NEW_ID and OLD_ID.

[image]

The NEW_ID will have its corresponding OLD_ID.

The output should be, if the OLD_ID value is alos available as one of the values in NEW_ID then it needs to be appended with "--".

The process needs to continue until the OLD_ID is not available as one of the values in NEW_ID.

In the attached example, you could see the the **NEW_ID with 29** is having **OLD_ID as 30**. However, the 30 is not available in NEW_ID and hence the process ends.

I tried to do a self join using the SQL queries but it doesn't work after 2 iterations.

Used merge option in Python but can't iterate for the number of times.(please ignore the below code if doesn't sounded correctly)

```
while n<=100:
    df1= pd.read_csv(path+iteration_file, encoding="utf-8")
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        joined_table = df1.merge(df1, left_on=row[0],right_on=row[1])
        iteration_file='Iteration.csv'
        joined_table.to_csv(iteration_file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding='utf-8')
    a=pow(2, n)
    b=2*a
    n=n+1
    print(str(a)+'-------'+str(b))
```

But this code resulted in the below error,

> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:1840 in _get_label_or_level_values
> raise KeyError(key)
>
> KeyError: 110748

I am looking for a solution which can be in any of the mediums such as **Python/SQL/Informatica**.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions

```
#[First]
import csv

with open(path+iteration_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f_in:
    P = set()
    c_in = csv.reader(f_in)
    _, mx = max(
        c_in, 
        key=lambda x:(P.add(x[0]), int(x[1]))[1]
    )
    f_in.seek(0)
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
        c_out = csv.writer(f_out)
        c_out.writerow(next(c_in))
        k = ""
        for rw in c_in:
            if rw[1] in P: 
                if not k:
                    k="--".join(range(int(rw[1]), mx))
                else:
                    _, k = k.split(rw[1]+'--')
                c_out.writerow([rw[0],k]) 
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Following the solution resulted in the below error,

  File ~\untitled2.py:44 in <lambda>

key=lambda x:(P.add(x[0]), int(x[1]))[1]

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Following the solution resulted in the below error, File ~\untitled2.py:44 in <lambda> key=lambda x:(P.add(x[0]), int(x[1]))[1] AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add' @user:1438644

Comment: @Mr.Sappeswaran  test again